# springboot get error when server starting in linux

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, war

First, there are two `Linux` servers.
I want to build a redundant `web server` on two servers.

I installed jre1.8.0 on two servers equally.
And I installed the same spring boot war file on two servers equally.

By the way ....
Server 1 normally goes up and works normally.
Error on server # 2 ....

I've copied war and tomcat on server # 1 to server # 2.
I still get an error on server # 2.

The duplication structure is almost the same as all the settings ...

jre path I checked .. 1.8.0 I checked and ..... ha ...... what is the problem?

I can not figure out why the error is only on server 2, because it is the same file with the same settings.

This is the error log.

---

:: Spring Boot ::  (v2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

> 2018-09-17 16:31:35 [DEBUG] [StartupInfoLogger.java]logStarting(53) :
>   Running with Spring Boot v2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, Spring
>   v5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
>
> 2018-09-17 16:31:35 [INFO ]
>   [SpringApplication.java]logStartupProfileInfo(701) : The following
>   profiles are active: dev
>
> 2018-09-17 16:31:35 [ERROR]
>   [LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java]report(42) :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:{path}/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinition.class

jar:file:{path}/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinition.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:{path}/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition



17-Sep-2018 16:31:35.890 ½É°¢ [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild:
```

start:

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/url]]

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V
>
> at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:259)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:797)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:421)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:340)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>           ... 10 more
>
> 17-Sep-2018 16:31:35.892 ½É°¢ [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web
>   application archive {Path}.War  java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/url]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> 17-Sep-2018 16:31:35.893 Á¤º¸ [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive {path}.war has finished in 3,617 ms 17-Sep-2018
>   16:31:35.894 Á¤º¸ [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory {path}/ROOT 17-Sep-2018 16:31:35.924 Á¤º¸
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory {path}/ROOT has finished in 30 ms
>   17-Sep-2018 16:31:35.926 Á¤º¸ [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-5555"] 17-Sep-2018 16:31:35.932 Á¤º¸ [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-4444"] 17-Sep-2018 16:31:35.934 Á¤º¸ [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3701 ms

Comment: You are mixing JAR files from different versions of Spring; 5.1.0.RC3 and 5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Make sure you are using only JAR files from one specific Spring version. Also, use an officially released version of Spring instead of a release candidate or nightly build snapshot, unless you have a really good reason to use a pre-release version.

Comment: improved formatting, post question as clear as possible , so that it may help contributors in understanding the question, e.g code blocks separate, and error stack trace or exceptions separate